# use select2 Auto Tokenization in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select2-rails

I use auto tokenization in my rails project.
I want read the tags from database and show to user. I use below code in controller and html file, but don't work for auto tokenization.(this code is ok for other select2, like ajax.)

problems_controller.rb

```
respond_to :html, :json
def index
  @problem = Problem.order('status asc').all
  respond_with @problem
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#e20").select2({
            tags: {
                url: "/problems.json",
                dataType: "json",
                results: function(data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map( data, function(problem, i) {
                            return { id: problem.id, text: problem.status }
                        } )
                    }
                }
            },
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
        });

    });

</script>
```

Where is the problem of my code? Why this code cannot read database information?

Comment: Do you have methods like name problem.

Comment: I have a problems_controller.rb and problem.rb (model) and a table in database by this name. In this project don't exist any other methods like name problem.

Comment: Then how that url: "/problems.json" will give you response, if it will give any response than this will defiantly wonder for me.

Comment: I use this code for a ajax dropdown like "ajax example" in [link](http://rails-select2-example.herokuapp.com/) and it is work, Read data from problems table in database and show on dropdown. But when I use this code for auto tokenization, cannot read information from database.

Comment: You mean that when we write problems.json it will take whole data from database no further queried for data and what attributes you have in problem table.

Comment: This code, just read one column from database(status column) and show them in dropdown. I forgot tell you, I have this code in top of my problems_controller : "respond_to :html, :json".